# МЯЛ - какой принцип русской графики?

Tags: письменность, алфавит, фонетика

Основной принцип русского письма - фонематический (свыше 90% написаний). Мы говорим [вл`ису], но пишем "в лесу", потому что там *фонема* **Э** (в сильной позиции, под ударением - "лес").

В слове *мял* на втором месте явно фонема **А** (звук ударный). Почему же мы не пишем там букву "а"? Какой принцип русского письма действует в этом случае?

---

*Уточнение 1*. Принципы всегда воплощаются в правилах. Правила фонематического принципа (ФП1) имеют такой вид: "фонема **Ж** обозначается буквой *ж*". Написание *мял* не противоречит ФП1. Но *правил* ФП1 недостаточно для выбора буквы *я* в слове "мял", потому что в этом случае правило раздваивается: "фонема **А** обозначается буквой *а* **или** буквой *я*", и мы не можем однозначно выбрать букву.

*Фонетический принцип* (ФП2), упомянутый [[@tmp](/users/1170/tmp)](/users/1170/tmp), имеет правила вида "звук [ж] обозначается буквой *ж*" - и точно так же раздваивается в написании *мял* (то есть ничего не объясняет); он слишком общий; оговорка *насколько это возможно средствами данного алфавита* должна раскрываться в каком-то более точном, специфическом принципе!

*Уточнение 2*. Обнаружить более сильный принцип можно там, где разные принципы вступают в противоречие друг с другом. ФП2 требует писать "на стале", но ФП1 побеждает, и мы уверенно можем говорить, что написание "на столе" вызвано требованиями **именно ФП1**. Случаи, когда ФП2 сильнее ФП1, тоже существуют, но они крайне редки в русском письме: это, например, приставки на -с (*раздать*, *рассвет*).

Comment: Краткий ответ. Потому что в слове "мял" звук "м" мягкий.
Сравните - "мал" и "мял". Не писать же "мьал"

Comment: @gecube, то есть вы хотите сказать, что мы выбираем буквы А или Я вовсе не для обозначения каких-либо свойств самой фонемы **А**, а для обозначения свойства предшествующей согласной фонемы???

И как же называется такой принцип?

Comment: >Не писать же "мьал"

:-) Югославы приблизительно так и пишут. 

(если кому-то интересно знать, как решали подобный вопрос в похожем на русский языке)

В один "прекрасный" момент они решили упростить кириллицу и убрали оттуда буквы Я, Ю и т.п. А вместо Й ввели J. Например, бывшая Югославия -- Jугославиja.

А если латинскими буквами написать "мял", то выйдет "mjal". 

Мой ник на такой манер написан - *Nikolja* - т.е. *Николя*. По франц. *Nikolas* -- прочитают как *Николас* скорее всего.

Comment: С кириллицей там у них немного мудрёней получилось, чем я написал, но я не уверен, что эти подробности кому-нибудь интересны на сайте "**Русский** язык".

Comment: @Nikolja, а Вы в скобочки напишите fr - тогда будет ясно =)

Comment: @gecube, а почему  нельзя писать мьал? Или, скажем, м'ал. (Это хуже, несвойственный знак).  Но можно и ввести новый знак. В польском, например, две "л", твердая и мягкая.

Comment: @DocentI, у себя дома можно так писать =) Но мы же ориентируемся на какие-то нормы, которые сложились со временем, не так ли?

Касательно мягкого знака - он показывает мягкость согласного, будучи на конце слова (**мель**, **конь**, **ночь**) или конце слога (**полька**). Или он может обозначать и наличие звука j (**мелью** vs **мелю**).

Comment: Нормы предписывают писать Мял и не вызывают вопросов. Я думала, обсуждается, _почему_ нормы стали такими. И не было ли других вариантов. Сам факт, что йотированные гласные могут обозначатьмягкость согласных, проходят в начальной школе.

Comment: @DocentI, ну, наверное, потому что, когда изобретали письменность над такой проблемой не задумывались. А судьба у знаков вроде "й", "ъ" и "ь" весьма непростая.

Comment: Собственно, мое замечание было не лингвистическое , а логическое. Я вспомнила Джерома  
> Зачем на младенцев надевают длинные рубашечки ?
Но сэр! Не надевать же на бедных малюток короткие!  

Впрочем, это -копание в мелочах. Похоже, я заразилась у нашего общего знакомого...

Comment: > :-) Югославы приблизительно так и пишут.

Всё-таки уточню. Сербы мягкий знак пишут слитно с согласной, как одну букву. Например, нюх (обоняние) пишется так -- њух. Любовь -- љубав и т.п.

Comment: Молодцы сербы! Очень логично.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В написании **мял** действует **слоговой принцип русской графики**. Вот что удалось найти о нём в интернете:

1) [Толковый словарь Ушакова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1029578):

> СЛОГОВО́Й, слоговая, слоговое (линг.).
>
> 1. прил. к слог в 1 знач. Слоговое письмо (в котором изображаются не
>    отдельные звуки, а сразу целые слоги).
>    Слоговой характер (или принцип)
>    письма.

2) http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-038.htm :

> Слоговой принцип русской графики
> заключается в том, что в русском
> письме в определенных случаях в
> качестве единицы письма выступает не
> буква, а слог. Такой слог, т.е.
> сочетание согласной и гласной букв,
> является цельным графическим
> элементом, части которого взаимно
> обусловлены. Слоговой принцип графики
> применяется в обозначении парных по
> твердости-мягкости согласных.

3) [Словарь лингвистических терминов Т.В. Жеребило](http://lingvistics_dictionary.academic.ru/3128/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%28%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%2C_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%29).

4) [гра́фика](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_literature/1428/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> система письменных знаков языка и
> принципы их соотношения со звуками.
> Основу рус. графики составляет
> алфавит. Её главный принцип – слоговой
> (силлабический). В графику включаются
> знаки препинания, значки типа %. В
> современном рус. письме используют
> элементы и иных график, напр.
> латиницы.

Литература и язык. Современная иллюстрированная энциклопедия. — М.: Росмэн. Под редакцией проф. Горкина А.П. 2006.

Comment: Дело в том, что это принцип нельзя рассматривать в ряду 
Это совершенно другая систематика. Звуковой (назовем так, чтобы не путать с фонетическим)- слоговой - иероглифический. 
Не надо путать теплое с широким.

Comment: Я не знаю, можно ли его "рассматривать", но он - **действует**, обеспечивает выбор нужных написаний.

Кстати, в зависимости от ширины, пальто может быть более или менее тёплым. Никакой путаницы.

Comment: Мне кажется, один из вас говорит о принципах графики, другой - о принципах орфографии.

Comment: Похоже на то. ))) 
И это лишний раз свидетельствует, куда заводят споры, если не договориться изначально о терминах. Правда, если договориться, то и споров не будет.

Хотя обычно в отношении принципы *графики* (я посмотрел их правильные название: фонографический, силлабографический, иероглифический, пиктографический) обсуждаются разве что в узком кругу специалистов, ибо предмета нет. "Слоговой" принцип - это, надо понимать, силлабографичский. Только он в русском выступает в чистом виде только в графемах Ё, Ю и Я. А в "мял" - какая-то его комбинация с фонографическим.

Comment: _Правила_ орфографии вступают в действие тогда (и только тогда), когда написание не могут однозначно определить принципы графики.

В приведённом примере (МЯЛ) применение правил орфографии не требуется.

Answer (score 2):

> Основной принцип русского письма - фонематический

С чего бы? 
Во-первых обычно выделяют всегда четыре или пять *основных* принципов: фонетический, фонематический, морфологический (морфемный), трационно-исторический и дифференционный (дифференцирующий), среди которых первым идёт фонетический, фонематический - только вторым. Во-вторых, стоит ли считать, "кто главнее", исходя из числа написаний?! Большинство написаний не противоречит не одному из первых трех принципов, да в общем-то и оставшимся двум. Основным из этих основных принципом я бы назвал морфологический принцип, поскольку именно он отражает суть и подход русского письма, ибо отступлений от него - единичны.

Далее, написание "мял" отнюдь не противоречит **фонетическому** принципу. Он звучит примерно как "передача звукового состава слова максимально близко к произношению: *насколько это возможно средствами данного алфавита*". Выделенный фрагмент объясняет то, что написание "мял" вполне себе фонетическое, ибо средствами нашего алфавита более точная передача невозможна. То, что вы подразумеваете свой постановкой вопроса, скорее всего - принцип графо-фонемного соответствия (ели не ошибаюсь, он носит название графо-фонетического): одной графеме всегда соответствует одна фонема и наоборот. Из известных мне алфавитов этому принципу в достаточной мере следует только грузинский и монгольский кириллический (последний с оговоркой на долгие гласные, отображаемые двумя графемами).

Ну и, собственно, ответ на вопрос. В рассматриваемом написании реализуются фонетический и морфологический принципы. Хотя и остальным (кроме фонематического) не противоречит.

А вообще по этой теме столько литературы. Только ткни. 
Вот, например, [статья](http://www.textology.ru/article.aspx?aId=195) хорошая.
Правда, частенько расходятся в основах, один спор "морфемный или морфологический" чего стоит. Кстати, в своем послании я постарался обойти известные мне острые углы различий подходов, чем в другом месте наверняка вызвал бы гнев представителей всех школ.

Comment: Много букв. :-) Написание МЯЛ *не противоречит* ни одному названному вами принципу. Но какой принцип определяющий? Всё-таки фонетический?

Да, и не бойтесь острых углов. Я называю фонемой то, что понимает под этим Московская школа. Ну и что? чего тут бояться? Если вы сторонник ленинградцев, ну, давайте я буду называть *её* "условной фонемой", мне не трудно.

Comment: >Написание МЯЛ не противоречит ни одному названному вами принципу  
  
Какое колесо в телеге главное? Всё...

Спорить не буду, пока Вы не отвктите, что конкретно понимаете под фонематическим принцмплм. Ваши формулировки заставляют задать этот вопрос.

Comment: Вы дали очень удачную ссылку на *статью хорошую* (М.В. Панова). Я понимаю под фонематическим принципом ровно то, что в этой статье: "**Фонематическое письмо** — это такое, в котором одни и те же буквы алфавита обозначают фонему во всех ее видоизменениях, как бы она ни звучала в том или ином фонетическом положении (И. С. Ильинская и В. Н. Сидоров 1953)".

Никаких других принципов в вопросе я не затрагивал. Я их как раз ищу (ну, вот **фонетический** уже нашёл - в той же статье Панова). Я не могу давать определения тому, чего пока не нашёл ("всем остальным" принципам).

Comment: Да не надо ничего искать. Вы говорили о фонетическом принципе, который якобы нарушен. Что-то же вы имели в виду под этим?! Хотя бы своими словами, что именно нарушено - и почему. 

А из данного определения фонематического принципа *не* следует, что в написании МЯЛ он нарушен. Вопрос был бы сколько-нибудь актуален, существуй в определении что-то вроде "разные знаки всегда соответствуют разным фонемам". Но такого там нет. Принцип (в такой формулировке) просто неприменим к данному написанию. Как, впрочем, и все остальные...

Comment: Я говорил о **фонематическом** принципе. И я не говорил, что он нарушен. См. Уточнения в моём вопросе. Вопрос (изначально) был совершенно конкретный: **какой принцип действует** (используется) в написании *мял* (а не какой принцип нарушен).

Comment: Фонематическому принципу (в указанной формулировке) написание "мял"  не противоречит.

Comment: Не противоречит. И не нарушен. Но и **не объясняет** написание.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю свои пять копеек :)

В слове "мял" буква "я" обозначает аллофон фонемы /а/, находящейся после **мягкого согласного**, т.е. написание этого слова не противоречит фонематическому принципу.

Comment: А как Вы его понимаете, этот принцип, дозвольте спросить?
Насколько могу судить, "фонематический принцип" в классическом понимании - обязательная передача одной фонемы во всех позициях с помощью одной графемы или одного и того же сочетания знака. Фонема "А" передаётся обычно знаком "А", в слове же мяд происходит отступления от этого принципа. Вот вопрос об обязательности передачи разных фонем разными знаками (судя по всему вы об этом) - это уже некое расширение принципа.

Comment: Термин же "аллофон" неизбежно заведет нас в бесконечные дебри неразрешенного и по сей день спора Московской и Петербуржской фонетических школ. Можно как-нибудь без него сформулировать Ваш основной тезис?!

Comment: @Koyani, я не говорил, что МЯЛ *противоречит* фонематическому принципу. И аллофоны тут совершенно ни при чём (звук А - в сильной позиции)!

Comment: stopkran, причём тут сильная позиция? Аллофон - это репрезентант фонемы, её конкретный вариант, который зависит от его фонетического окружения. То есть определяющими для аллофона являются не сила или слабость позиции, а качества окружающих звуков. В данном случае имеет место быть предшествующий мягкий согласный звук [м'],который представлен на письме графемой "я". Если написать в этом слове "а" то получится "мал" - совсем другое слово. Потеряли букву "а"? Транскрибируйте слово: [м'ал] - вот она.

Comment: tmp, без аллофона - никак.

Comment: stopkran, совсем забыла, определяющий принцип в этом слове - фонематический.

Comment: @Koyani, нет :-). Я долго рылся в интернете, и нашёл точное определение нужного принципа русской графики. Завтра напишу в ответе.